# Laravel Add Additional Rows to an Eloquent Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, collections, eloquent

I want to add an "On This Day" feature which should display records from The Previous Years. I have some Entries, all of them have a 'date' attribute. This is what I've been trying so far:

```
public function filterByDay($id){
    $entries = Entry::where('id', $id)->get();
    $currentDay = $entries[0]->date;
    $oldestYear = Entry::orderBy('date','asc')->first()->date;
    $previousYear = $currentDay;
    while($previousYear >= $oldestYear ){
        $previousYear = $currentDay->subYear();
        $entries->push(Entry::where('date', $previousYear)->get());
    }
    return view('home')->with(compact('entries'));
}
```

I must send a Collection of "Entry" type from this controller method so that I can use $entry->title etc in the view. But whenever I'm using $entries->push(...) , I'm getting a Collection instance, not Entry instance. How can I convert the Collection back into Entry instance? Or what is the alternative? I'm using Laravel 5.5. Some help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can just call "->first()" instead of "->get()" to get one entry instead of the collection: $entries->push(Entry::where('date', $previousYear)->first());

Comment: for some reason, I'm getting "trying to get property 'date' of non-object. But I do have 'date' attribute in Entry model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`whereDay, whereYear and whereMonth`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) methods to achieve it in one liner:

```
$entries = Entry::where('id', $id)->get();
$today = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$oldestYear = Entry::orderBy('date','asc')->first()->date;
$allEntries = Entry::whereDay('date', $today->day)
                ->whereYear('date', '>=', $oldestYear)
                ->whereMonth('date', $today->month)
                ->get();

return view('home')->with(compact('allEntries'));
```

Comment: in $oldestYear, you're getting a Timestamp, not just the Year. I changed it to get the Year only. But this query returns no rows while it should return 1 row..

Comment: I also added a get() at the end and it's working perfectly now. Thank you. Please edit your answer and I will accept it as the Right Answer.

Comment: you should replace the current $oldestYear assignment with this:
 $oldestYear = Entry::orderBy('date','asc')->first()->date->day; However, I have accepted the answer.